# Simple solution to this algebraic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Consider this system of equations with two variables $x,y$ and all positive parameters
$$\frac{2(x-w_1)}{a_1}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,,\quad\frac{2(y-w_2)}{a_2}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$
It at most amounts to an algebraic equation of degree 4, which is always solvable in principle. But is there any possibility to explicitly solve this one? Hopefully some not too complicated form of solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from 
\begin{equation}
\frac{(x-w_1)^2}{a_1^2} + \frac{(y-w_2)^2}{a_2^2} = \frac{1}{2^2}
\end{equation}
that
the solutions are lying on the ellipses.

Thus
\begin{equation}
y = w_2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{a_2^2}{2^2} - \frac{a_2^2(x-w_1)^2}{a_1^2}}
\end{equation}
Then plugging this into the below
\begin{equation}
\frac{4}{a_1^2}(x-w_1)^2(x^2+y^2) = x^2
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
-x^2 + \frac{4}{a_1^2}(x-w_1)^2\left(x^2 + \left[w_2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{a_2^2}{2^2} - \frac{a_2^2(x-w_1)^2}{a_1^2}} \right]^2\right) = 0
\end{equation}
which is
\begin{equation}
-x^2 + \frac{4}{a_1^2}(x-w_1)^2\left(x^2 + w_2^2 +  \frac{a_2^2}{2^2} - \frac{a_2^2(x-w_1)^2}{a_1^2} \pm 2w_2\sqrt{\frac{a_2^2}{2^2} - \frac{a_2^2(x-w_1)^2}{a_1^2}} \right) = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks. This is obvious... But any idea to solve it?

Comment: @huotuichang I just want to mention that there are a lot of algebraic equations whose solutions can not explicitly written in a closed form. Think about the solutions of $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$.

Comment: But an algebraic equation of degree less than 5 has [closed-form solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_solution) always.

Comment: @huotuichang Didn't aware of the closed form of quartic function. Just to be clear that algebraic equation is more broader concept than such quartic equation. $\sum_{0\le i,j \le 2} a_{ij}x^iy^i = 0$ is an algebraic equation of degree 4 whose solutions do not have a closed form (which is a huge theme of Algebraic geometry).

Comment: Surely I mean univariate, since my problem can be reduced to this.

Comment: @huotuichang But your problem is bi-variate, involving $x$ and $y$ isn't it?

Comment: I said it can be reduced to univariate of degree at most 4.

Comment: @huotuichang You are right! This can be reduced to a single quartic equation. Interesting!...

Comment: @huotuichang Please find my solutions and want to have your opinion :)

Comment: Nice try...It's wrong if you plug your solution into the original equations.

Comment: @huotuichang Can you find which step went wrong? Hum... you're right. The solutions I found satisfy the ellipses equations but not the original one.

Comment: I guess it went wrong from the line 'Subtracting...'?

Comment: @huotuichang Details are added.

Comment: Please erase from [Details added]. Just don't leave a wrong solution there.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{2(x-w_1)}{a_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2(y-w_2)}{a_2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2=1 \\ \implies
\left(\frac{2(x-w_1)}{a_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2(y-w_2)}{a_2}\right)^2=1$$

This is an ellipse. Solutions are $$x-w_1=\frac{a_1}{2}\cos\theta \\ y-w_2 =\frac{a_2}{2}\sin\theta\quad \forall \quad\theta\in[0,2\pi]$$